# set head to NULL ('NULL' : undeclared identifier)

Tags: c++, pointers, null

I defined a linked list in C++. I am trying to set a NULL value to the variable head (in the constructor of `Movie_LinkedList`), but I got:

**movie.h(40): error C2065: 'NULL' : undeclared identifier**

please note ***that I can't include any library except of `iostream`***

```
#define NAME_LEN 100

class Movie_DataBase
{
private:
    long int m_Code;
    char m_Name[NAME_LEN];
    bool belongs_to_netwroks[2];    
public:
    Movie_DataBase();
    Movie_DataBase(char movie_name[],long int movie_code);
};


class Movie_LinkedList
{
private:
    class Movie_Node
    {
    public:
        Movie_DataBase* data;
        Movie_Node* prev;
        Movie_Node* next;
    public:
        Movie_Node();

    };
    Movie_Node* head; //pointer to the first node in the linkedlist
    int a;
public:
    void set_movie();
    Movie_LinkedList() { head = NULL; }

};
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: That's because `NULL` hasn't been defined. Either define it or set `head = 0`

Comment: Why did you delete your code?

Comment: because there are students that can copy my code..

Comment: They still can; it's in the edit history.

Comment: Woe to those students who copy broken code! :-P

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As written, `NULL` isn't defined in your program. Usually, that's defined in a standard header file -- specifically `<cstddef>` or `<stddef.h>`. Since you're restricted to `iostream`, if yours doesn't get `NULL` implicitly from that header, you can use `0` or, in C++11, `nullptr`, which is a keyword and doesn't require a header. (It is not recommended to define `NULL` yourself. It might work sometimes, but it is technically illegal.)

Comment: including a header file for a macro is unnecessary. I am not the downvoter though

Comment: OP is not allowed to include headers!

Comment: @Aniket The _only_ way to get `NULL` is by including one of the standard headers which define it.

Comment: that's certainly not true @JamesKanze the other way is posted below as my answer

Comment: @Aniket Your answer is wrong.  It's illegal to define `NULL` in your code (at least if you include any standard headers).

Answer (score 8):

You should include `<stddef.h>` or `<cstddef>`.

However you can use `0` or `nullptr` too.

Comment: I think `nullptr` is only for c++11

Comment: Op is not allowed to include headers. and assigning a pointer to an integer will cause compiler error.

Comment: No it won't. Try `int* p = 0;` Very common.

Comment: hmm @metal try this: `int *p = 0x1` - however the compiler says it is ok to assign 0 but not 1

Comment: Thus spake the Creator: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#nullptr  Note also the references.

Comment: @Aniket That's because _a constant integral expression evaluating to 0_ is a null pointer constant, and converts implicitly to a null pointer of any type.  How did you think `NULL` was defined?

Answer (score 4):

use the following include:

```
#include <stddef.h>
```

Comment: @Aniket He has to, otherwise he cannot use `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

No libraries needed!

on the top of the header file,

do this:

```
#ifndef NULL
#define NULL (0)
#endif
```

Comment: This is forbidden by the standard, and results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Worse: the definition you give isn't even legal.

Comment: @JamesKanze it is legal now

Comment: The problem was the difference between `(void *)0` being NULL in C and `0` in C++ because of a certain incompatibilities.

Comment: Provided it is in one of the standard headers.  You're not allowed to provide definitions of things that are in the standard headers.

Comment: but he is not including standard headers. And you can always undefine any macro(even in standard libraries)

Comment: There's no real difference between traditional C and C++ here.  `NULL` has always been `0`, since the days of Kernighan and Richie.  For some unknown reason, the C standards committee decided to _allow_ an additional form, but it wasn't in K&R C, and certainly isn't traditional.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26649/discussion-between-aniket-and-james-kanze)

Comment: `<iostream>` is a standard header.  And while it is legal to undefine `NULL`, it's not legal for you to define it.

Comment: See §17.6.4.3.1/1: "A translation unit that includes a standard
library header shall not `#define` or `#undef` names declared in
any standard library header."

Comment: A proscription routinely violated, alas, when it comes to the min/max macros.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` isn't actually part of the core C or C++ language; it's defined to be 0 in stddef.h

Since you're using C++, prefer `nullptr`, which is a keyword, and typed. (Assuming it's available. It's part of C++11, so technically not all compilers will support it; practically, you'd be hard-pressed to find a compiler that doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this. So need to add `<string.h>` headers.

```c
#include<string.h>

typedef struct{
 node *head;
 node *current;
 int size
}list;

void appendList(list *l, int n){
  if(l->head == NULL){
    
  }
}

int main(){
 return 0;
}
```

I tried to create a `linkedlist`, and I encountered this.